# Xcode 4 not outputting .app package when building OSX project

Tags: xcode, xcode4, package

My Xcode 4 project is not actually building the .app bundle that it is supposed to when it finishes building. What are some reasons why this might be happening? The build process is not giving any errors, but it simply isn't giving me an app bundle which I can execute. What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The build output directory changed in [xcode4](/questions/tagged/xcode4). Open the Organizer (projects tab):

[image: eXcode 4 - Organizer - Projects]

The built .app is located in the Derived Data directory, in this case:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GKTapper-dbndueflsmkgokewelsloryzthni
```